# how to delete the same file which is uploaded in a directory?

Tags: java, file, servlets, file-upload, file-io

there is folder temp to which the files uploaded by users are stored. the file name is same for each user but the content is different. Each user uploads a file called abc.xlsx. now when "A" user uploads abc.xlsx file after processing that file should be deleted. But currently i am deleting all the files in the folder. which is a problem since one more user might be uploading the file ehich will be cleared too. So i was thinking of renaming the file by appending the username to the file and then delete that particular file.

This is the file upload:

```
ProcessForm uploadForm = (ProcessForm)form;

         String folderpath = "servers/temp";
         String filePath = folderpath + "/" + uploadForm.getUploadedFile().getFileName();
```

This will delete all the files in the folder:

```
 String tempPath = folderpath; 
            File file = new File(tempPath);
            File[] files = file.listFiles(); 
            for (File f:files) 
            {
                if (f.isFile() && f.exists()) 
                { 
                    f.delete();
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you use Java 7+?

Comment: using java 7 version

Comment: _"i was thinking of renaming the file by appending the username to the file"_ what happened then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got it. This is working as expected:

```
         String folderpath = "servers/temp";
         String filePath = folderpath + "/" + "abc_"+user.getUsername()+".xlsx";

         outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
         outputStream.write(uploadForm.getUploadedFile().getFileData());
```

Code to delete file:

```
        File file = new File(filePath);
        boolean fileDelete = file.delete();

            if (fileDelete) 
            { 
                    mLogger.debug("successfully deleted");
            } else {
                mLogger.error("cant delete a file");
            }
```